# Why the function call so many times in javascript, codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, function, codeigniter

Using codeigniter framework, First i get **inputs fields** from database and display in view by its type. We can create field dynamically and append after it by button. You want to know that we can change field type by selecting options. Whether select the **radio option** the tr(radio box) having input field will be created for get number to generate radio options. After getting number, field will dynamically created. After all the problem is when I select the radio option the java script function call single time at first attempt. but on second attempt it calls many times.

**View**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="AddNewField()
 Add Field</button>

<?php $i=1000; 
   foreach($field_rec as $index=>$val){
    $customeFiled_value=str_replace(array("_"),' ',$index);?>
    <tr id="<?php echo $i;?>">
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" title="" name="field[]" class="form-control text" value="<?php echo $customeFiled_value;?>" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input title="" name="alternate_text[<?= $index ?>]" class="form-control alternate_text" value="<?= ((array_key_exists($index, $alternate_fields))?$alternate_fields[$index]:'') ?>"  type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control typeOption" name="type[]" onclick="showRadioBox(<?php echo $i;?>)">
                    <option value='textbox' <?php if($val=='textbox'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>Text Box</option>
                    <option value='textarea' <?php if($val=='textarea'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>Text Area</option>
                    <option value='date' <?php if($val=='date'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>Date</option>
                    <option value='radio' <?php if($val=='radio'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>Radio</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>   
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="RemoveThisItem('<?php echo $i;?>')" title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o"></i></a>
            </div>
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <?php $i++; 
    }
}?>
```

**JavaScript**

//Add Field

```
function AddNewField(){
    var tId=$.now(); 

    $('.tbody').append("<tr id='"+tId+"'>"+
                        "<td>"+
                           "<div class='form-group'>"+
                                "<input type='text' class='form-control text' name='field[]'/>"+
                            "</div>"+
                        "</td>"+
                        "<td>"+
                            "<div class='form-group'>"+
                                "<select class='form-control typeOption' name='type[]' onclick='showRadioBox("+tId+")'>"+
                                    "<option value='textbox'>Text Box</option>"+
                                    "<option value='textarea'>Text Area</option>"+
                                    "<option value='date'>Date</option>"+
                                    "<option value='radio'>Radio</option>"+
                                "</select>"+
                            "</div>"+
                        "</td>"+
                        "<td>"+
                            "<div class='form-group'>"+
                                "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='RemoveThisItem("+tId+")' title='Remove'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-trash-o'></i></a>"+
                            "</div>"+
                        "</td>"+
                    "</tr>");
}
```

//Show Radio box

```
function showRadioBox(id){
  $('.typeOption').change(function(id){
        if($(this).val() == 'radio'){
            $(this).closest('tr').after("<tr class='showRadioBox'>"+
                                            "<td colspan='2'>"+
                                                "<div class='form-group'>"+
                                                    "<label for=''><b>Enter number of Radio Option:</b></label>"+
                                                        "<input type='text' class='form-control getRadioValue' name='test'/>"+
                                                    "</div>"+
                                                "</td>"+
                                                "<td style='padding-top:25px;'>"+
                                                    "<button type='button'  class='btn btn-info btn-block ' onclick='createRadioOption(this)' id='"+id+"'>Create Options</button>"+
                                                "</td>"+
                                            "</tr>"+
                                            "<tr>"+
                                             "<td colspan='3' class='radioInputsCol'>"+
                       // append inputs for option here
                                             "</td>"+
                                            "</tr>");
        }
        else{
            $(this).closest('tr').next('.showRadioBox').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

//Create number of fields for radio options

```
function createRadioOption(e){

    var val = $(e).closest('tr').find('.getRadioValue').val();
    var tr=$(e).closest('tr');
    var sib=tr[0].nextSibling;
    var td=$(sib).children('td');

    $(td).empty();
    for(i=0; i<val; i++){
        $(td).append('<div class="col-md-4">'+
                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Radio option-'+(i+1)+'">'+
                    '</div>');
    }
}
```

Comment: You call `showRadioBox` on every click on the `.typeOption` select field, and inside that _each time_ you add a new change handler to it ... Don’t nest those two actions into each other, that’s nonsense. Assign handler functions for click and change separately.

Comment: how can i call separately the same function?Do you mean,  Should I make another function to call separately?

Comment: What “same function” are you talking about? If you want to attach the same handler function for multiple event types, then use `.on`. (And you should really try and bind the click event via JavaScript/jQuery in the first place, and not via `onclick` HTML attribute. Not only is that a weird mixture of styles, it can also easily lead to additional glitches.)

Comment: Yeah, i got it. it really works fine, thank you for your suggestion